# How types conditional generic, for params entered in function?

Tags: typescript

I ask for help from more experienced developers

I want to write a construction that will return a type based on the fact
What type was passed to the parameter, nothing happens due to lack of theory

This is the direction I went in, but it still doesn’t work as it should (in type A, it’s like the entered data doesn’t get into T)
Please tell me how to implement this?

```
type C = {
    type: string
}

type A<T> = T extends C[] ? C[] : C

type Gen = <T>(a: A<T>) => A<T>

const gen: Gen = (a) => {
    return a
}

//work
const res = gen({
    type: 'string'
})

//not work
const res = gen([{
    type: 'string'
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct typing of your `Gen` type is:

```ts
type Gen = <T>(a: T) => T
```

So why does your code works for the first `res` function but not for the second one. Well, that's how unconstrained type variables work. When you define it as:

```ts
type A<T> = T extends C[] ? C[] : C

type Gen = <T>(a: A<T>) => A<T>
// this one is almost the same as writing
// type Gen = (a: C) => C
```

You are effectively telling `Gen` type is a function that can handle *any* `T` type it may get. Typescript passes *unconstrained* (can be anything) `T` into `A<T>`. `A<T>` checks wheter it extends `C[]`. Well, it doesn't. To extend `C[]` we have to *constrain* type `T` to fit that requirement.

But if you constrain it to the `C[]` then only the second `res` function will typecheck correctly:

```ts
type Gen = <T extends C[]>(a: A<T>) => A<T>
// this one is almost the same as
// type Gen = (a: C[]) => C[]


const res1 = gen({ // Argument of type '{ type: string; }' 
                   // is not assignable to parameter of type 'C[]'
    type: 'string'
})

const res2 = gen([{ // no error
    type: 'string'
}])
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nl01RN)